# Titanium HTTPClient doesn't return the full response

Tags: json, get, httpclient, response, appcelerator-titanium

I have a problem with the[HTTPClient](https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Network.HTTPClient-property-onload) in Appcelerator Titanium.
I am using it for a GET request to the following endpoint:

```
https://rxnav.nlm.nih.gov/REST/interaction/list.json?rxcuis=5640+53694
```

It should return a response like this:

```
{  
   "nlmDisclaimer":"It is not the intention of NLM to provide specific medical advice, but rather to provide users with information to better understand their health and their medications. NLM urges you to consult with a qualified physician for advice about medications.",
   "userInput":{  
      "sources":[  
         ""
      ],
      "rxcuis":[  
         "5640",
         "53694"
      ]
   },
   "fullInteractionTypeGroup":[  
      {  
         "sourceDisclaimer":"DrugBank is intended for educational and scientific research purposes only and you expressly acknowledge and agree that use of DrugBank is at your sole risk. The accuracy of DrugBank information is not guaranteed and reliance on DrugBank shall be at your sole risk. DrugBank is not intended as a substitute for professional medical advice, diagnosis or treatment..[www.drugbank.ca]",
         "sourceName":"DrugBank",
         "fullInteractionType":[  
            {  
               "comment":"Drug1 (rxcui = 53694, name = nimesulide, tty = IN). Drug2 (rxcui = 5640, name = Ibuprofen, tty = IN). Drug1 is resolved to nimesulide, Drug2 is resolved to Ibuprofen and interaction asserted in DrugBank between Nimesulide and Ibuprofen.",
               "minConcept":[  
                  {  
                     "rxcui":"53694",
                     "name":"nimesulide",
                     "tty":"IN"
                  },
                  {  
                     "rxcui":"5640",
                     "name":"Ibuprofen",
                     "tty":"IN"
                  }
               ],
               "interactionPair":[  
                  {  
                     "interactionConcept":[  
                        {  
                           "minConceptItem":{  
                              "rxcui":"53694",
                              "name":"nimesulide",
                              "tty":"IN"
                           },
                           "sourceConceptItem":{  
                              "id":"DB04743",
                              "name":"Nimesulide",
                              "url":"http://www.drugbank.ca/drugs/DB04743#interactions"
                           }
                        },
                        {  
                           "minConceptItem":{  
                              "rxcui":"5640",
                              "name":"Ibuprofen",
                              "tty":"IN"
                           },
                           "sourceConceptItem":{  
                              "id":"DB01050",
                              "name":"Ibuprofen",
                              "url":"http://www.drugbank.ca/drugs/DB01050#interactions"
                           }
                        }
                     ],
                     "severity":"N/A",
                     "description":"The risk or severity of adverse effects can be increased when Ibuprofen is combined with Nimesulide."
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Instead with the titanium HTTPClient I get only this in response:

```
{  
   "nlmDisclaimer":"It is not the intention of NLM to provide specific medical advice, but rather to provide users with information to better understand their health and their medications. NLM urges you to consult with a qualified physician for advice about medications.",
   "userInput":{  
      "sources":[  
         ""
      ],
      "rxcuis":[  
         "5640+53694"
      ]
   }
}
```

The code to make the request is the following:

```
var client = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({

        onload: function() {
            console.log(this.responseText);
            var json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            console.log(json);
        },

        onerror: function() {
            console.log(this.responseText);
        }

    });

    var url = "https://rxnav.nlm.nih.gov/REST/interaction/list.json?rxcuis=5640+53694";
    client.open("GET", url);
    client.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    client.send();
```

I've also tried to return xml instead of json but it is the same thing, only the first part of the response is returned. Any clue on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran your code and seems to be working fine for me:

```
[INFO]  {"nlmDisclaimer":"It is not the intention of NLM to provide specific medical advice, but rather to provide users with information to better understand their health and their medications. NLM urges you to consult with a qualified physician for advice about medications.","userInput":{"sources":[""],"rxcuis":["5640","53694"]},"fullInteractionTypeGroup":[{"sourceDisclaimer":"DrugBank is intended for educational and scientific research purposes only and you expressly acknowledge and agree that use of DrugBank is at your sole risk. The accuracy of DrugBank information is not guaranteed and reliance on DrugBank shall be at your sole risk. DrugBank is not intended as a substitute for professional medical advice, diagnosis or treatment..[www.drugbank.ca]","sourceName":"DrugBank","fullInteractionType":[{"comment":"Drug1 (rxcui = 53694, name = nimesulide, tty = IN). Drug2 (rxcui = 5640, name = Ibuprofen, tty = IN). Drug1 is resolved to nimesulide, Drug2 is resolved to Ibuprofen and interaction asserted in DrugBank between Nimesulide and Ibuprofen.","minConcept":[{"rxcui":"53694","name":"nimesulide","tty":"IN"},{"rxcui":"5640","name":"Ibuprofen","tty":"IN"}],"interactionPair":[{"interactionConcept":[{"minConceptItem":{"rxcui":"53694","name":"nimesulide","tty":"IN"},"sourceConceptItem":{"id":"DB04743","name":"Nimesulide","url":"http://www.drugbank.ca/drugs/DB04743#interactions"}},{"minConceptItem":{"rxcui":"5640","name":"Ibuprofen","tty":"IN"},"sourceConceptItem":{"id":"DB01050","name":"Ibuprofen","url":"http://www.drugbank.ca/drugs/DB01050#interactions"}}],"severity":"N/A","description":"The risk or severity of adverse effects can be increased when Ibuprofen is combined with Nimesulide."}]}]}]}
```

Using the Ti SDK 6.0.1.GA in an iOS app.

Keep in mind that if you are running this on Android there might be a chance that logcat is cutting the logs since there is a limit of characters. You may have want to try to print `console.log(json.fullInteractionTypeGroup)` to make sure you are getting that key back.

If that doesn't work, update your question with you SDK version, Alloy version, project target, etc.

Comment: I am using the 5.2.0, could be the problem? And yes, I've tried to log everything from the json. For now I've solved using another custom web service which will return the full response to the titanium client.

Comment: Then maybe it's something with the web service. Can you try either the SDK 6.0.1 or to run your app on iOS?